# call the java script method from href

Tags: javascript

I have this variable file_link declared in one of my javascript function, I would like to call the get_links method from this variable, please help me with the correct syntax.

```
var filelink = "<a href='javascript:get_links(" + source_id + ")'>" + name + "</a>";
```

Comment: Why do you have that inline javascript in the first place? Do you have control over that piece of... code. Also why are you writing HTML in JS?

Comment: From this variable... which holds a string of HTML? I don't understand.

Comment: @PeeHaa because I have to create dynamic HTML elements

Comment: In that case use proper DOM methods.

Comment: @PeeHaa can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit and update your question describing what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the function get_links and put the result in the filelink variable:

```
var filelink = get_links(source_id);
```

If this is not the case please try to put more details about what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This would be too long for a comment. But you should build the link(s) using the DOM methods. I have also added a quick example of an eventlistener (not really sure whether this is what you are after, at the very least you may want to expand no the selector used).

```
(function() {
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'A') return;

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-source-id'));
  });

  var name = 'somename',
      source_id = '1';

  var filelink = document.createElement('a');
  filelink.setAttribute('href', '#');
  filelink.setAttribute('data-source-id', source_id);
  filelink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));

  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(filelink);
}());
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/smvBG